# UIDocumentInteraction Controller + QLPreviewController

Tags: iphone

we are using documentinteraction controller for previewing documents. for 4.2 we are using QLPreviewController.

Now we are trying to achieve showing multiple documents with preview controller. when user scrolls horizontally need to show next document from list in preview controller.

So question is ... is it doable? or any work around this. what box.net are using for showing documents?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So since iOS 6, the minimum supported OS version is 4.3, you can simply remove the case for 4.2 & below.